# Function to check a value in a String

Tags: regex, string, substring

I'm working with an application that tries to check the location of an user in a User Directory.

I have strings similar to:

```
CN=John Mayor,OU=Users,OU=NA,OU=Local,DC=domain,DC=application,DC=com
```

or

```
CN=Annette Luis Morgant,OU=Users,OU=CH,OU=Local,DC=domain,DC=application,DC=com
```

I'm trying to filter in javascript the string in order to print out ONLY the value of the **second** `"OU"`.
So for the first case it will be `"NA"`, for the second case it will be `"CH"`.

Trying to use substring and trim or something similar, but I'm confusing myself! 
Can you help me?
Thanks!!!!

edit-----
This is what I was trying to do:

```
public class SplitUser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String MyStringContent = "CN=John Mayor,OU=Users,OU=NA,OU=Local,DC=domain,DC=application,DC=com";
    String[] arrSplit = MyStringContent.split(",");
    for (int i=0; i < arrSplit.length; i++)
    {
     System.out.println(arrSplit[i]);
    }   
    //System.out.println(arrSplit[2]);
    String p = arrSplit[2].substring(3, arrSplit[2].length());
    System.out.println(p);
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're likely to get more help if you can show your effort, otherwise it seems a bit like "please do my work for me".

Comment: This is a community were we can help each other. I'm trying to find a solution and in the same time writing to this forum.

Comment: We help eachother, but some proof of effort is well recieved. Just bear in mind for the next time ;-). Not just because of the "please do my work" thing. Showing your efforts will make the people help you easier (by either noticing some bug on your tries or by either not trying things you already tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with this:

`(?:,|^)OU=[^,]+(?=.*?,OU=([^,]+)).*`

It will work even if there are some other FOO=BAR values inserted among the "OU"'s

Explained:

```
(?:,|^)  # start by begin of line or ','
OU=   
[^,]+    #Anything but a ',' 1 or more times
         #We have found 1 OU, let's find the next 
(?= # Lookahead expression
    .*? # Anything (ungreedy)
    ,OU=
    ([^,]+)
)
.* # Anything, just to match the whole line 
   # and avoid multiple matches for the same line (g flag)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NKuuom/1/)

Comment: If it worked for you, you may accept my answer. Also, you could put the details from "your answer" into the details of the main question. "Answers" are supposed to be for providing solutions. Thank you!